# Case statement with calculation SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to get an output from a case statement(which is being used in SQL select statement) and along with the output i want to increment the value of a local variable.

```
CASE WHEN convert(int,d.ApplyEscalatorAfterHowManyYears)>0 AND   
y.num>=convert(int,d.ApplyEscalatorAfterHowManyYears) THEN ((convert(money,d.AnnualAmount)*(d.Escalator*@counter))/100) else 0 end)
```

there might be some syntax error.

I don't know whether the following query will be help in getting the understanding or not.

```
declare @counter int 
set @counter = 1
;WITH myTbl AS (SELECT * FROM(  
SELECT src.ForecastAccountID, src.AccountName, src.RepeatNumber,src.AttributeName,src.Value  
FROM (SELECT a.ForecastID, a.ForecastAccountID, a.RepeatNumber, a.AccountNumber, c.AccountName, src.AttributeName, fa.Value  
FROM CoA c WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN (Forecast_Account a WITH (NOLOCK)  INNER JOIN (  
(SELECT s.AttributeSetID, s.AttributeSetName, a.AttributeID, a.AttributeName, a.ColumnOrder, a.SignMultiplier  
FROM Attribute_Set s INNER JOIN Attribute a ON s.[AttributeSetID] = a.[AttributeSetID]  
WHERE (((s.AttributeSetID)=3))) src  
 INNER JOIN Forecast_Attribute fa WITH (NOLOCK) ON src.[AttributeID] = fa.[AttributeID]) ON a.[ForecastAccountID] = fa.[ForecastAccountID]) ON c.AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber  
WHERE (((a.ForecastAccountID)=332))) src  
GROUP BY src.ForecastAccountID, src.AccountName, src.RepeatNumber,src.AttributeName,src.Value  
) AS t  
 PIVOT (min(Value) FOR AttributeName IN ([Counterparty],[Memo],[CoverPeriodBegin],[CoverPeriodEnd],[PaymentFrequency],[AdditionalYearsToRepeat],[AnnualAmount],[Escalator],[ApplyEscalatorAfterHowManyYears],[Payment1Date],[Payment1Percent],[Payment2Date],[Payment2Percent],[Payment3Date],[Payment3Percent],[Payment4Date],[Payment4Percent])) AS pvt),

  num(num) AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT num+1 FROM num WHERE num < 60)   
--INSERT INTO Forecast_Data(ForecastAccountID,CashGAAP,TheDate,Amount,LastUpdated,UpdatedBy)   
SELECT d.ForecastAccountID, 'GAAP' AS CashGAAP, dateadd(M, (x.num + 12*y.num), convert(datetime,d.CoverPeriodBegin)) AS TheDate,   
Round((convert(money,d.AnnualAmount)+ (CASE WHEN convert(int,d.ApplyEscalatorAfterHowManyYears)>0 AND   
y.num>=convert(int,d.ApplyEscalatorAfterHowManyYears) THEN ((convert(money,d.AnnualAmount)*(d.Escalator*@counter))/100) else 0 end))/(DATEDIFF(M,d.CoverPeriodBegin,d.CoverPeriodEnd)+1),2) AS Amount,  
GETDATE() AS LastUpdated,   
'jhogg1' AS UpdatedBy,y.num FROM num x,num y, myTbl AS d   
WHERE (x.num BETWEEN 0 AND (datediff(M, convert(datetime,d.CoverPeriodBegin), convert(datetime,d.CoverPeriodEnd)))) AND (y.num BETWEEN 0 AND convert(int,d.AdditionalYearsToRepeat));
```

**i want to increment the value of @counter in case statement along with the calculation.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this logic but it won't help in your example :

```
declare @mytest table (val1 int)

declare @test int = 60
declare @cur int = 0
declare @counter int = 1

while (@cur < @test)
BEGIN
    insert into @mytest select @cur
    set @cur = @cur + 1
END

select @counter = @counter + case when val1%2=0 then 1 else 0 end)
from @mytest

select @counter
```

For me you cannot do that so easily. Sql server is managing your data as one package, it's not imaginable for him to do an iterate. You have other software to do that :) not such a complicated logic.

Perhaps you could try to execute your code with dense_rank, or rank_number.

if the performance are not so bad i would do like this :

```
declare @mytest table (val1 int)

declare @test int = 60
declare @cur int = 0

while (@cur < @test)
BEGIN
    insert into @mytest select @cur
    set @cur = @cur + 1
END

select case when b.val1%2=0 then b.val1 else 0 end + ISNULL(p.counters,0)
from @mytest b
left outer join (select val1, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by val1) as counters from @mytest where val1%2 =0) p on p.val1 = b.val1
```

This is of course a simple example, but it should fit to what you want to do with more complex join and where clause :)